# Meaning of Jacobians satisfying $J_F^{-1}(J_F^{-1})^T = c\mathrm{Id}$ for a map $F$ between two domains?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, reference-request, jacobian

Let $F\colon \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ be a $C^1$ invertible map between smooth domains $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that the Jacobian matrix of $F$, called $J_F$, is invertible and satisfies the property
$$J_F^{-1}(J_F^{-1})^T = c\mathrm{Id}$$ for some constant function $c$. Of course the elements of $J_F$ and its inverse are functions of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Do such maps have some name attached to them and do they imply anything about the domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ (or $F$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c>0$, such maps are called **conformal** if $\det J_F>0$ and **anticonformal** if $\det J_F<0$. Notice that I didn't specify a point at which $\det J_F$ is evaluated. That's because the sign can't change, which I will discuss later.

We will take a look at your function first, and then at conformal functions in general.

So you have a map $F$ with invertible Jacobian such that

$$J_F^{-1}(J_F^{-1})^T=c\operatorname{Id},$$

where $c\neq0$, since both factors on the left are invertible, so their product has to be invertible as well. Since $c>0$, we can rearrange this to

$$(\sqrt cJ_F)(\sqrt c J_F)^T=\operatorname{Id},$$

which makes $\sqrt c J_F$ orthogonal (see lisyarus' answer). In other words, $\sqrt c J_F$ represents a rotation, possibly combined with a reflection. Multiplying (=dilating) by $\sqrt c^{-1}$ gives us $J_F$, so $J_F$ is a rotation-dilation, possibly combined with a reflection. Another word for such a linear map is **conformal** (without reflection) or **anticonformal** (with reflection). They form the conformal group $CO(\mathbb R^n)$ (**c***onformal* **o***rthogonal*). A $C^1$ function with (anti)conformal Jacobian in $x_0$ is itself called (anti)conformal in $x_0$. It is called (anti)conformal if it is (anti)conformal on its entire domain. Intuitively, conformal and anticonformal functions are those which keep angles between smooth intersecting lines invariant. So a rectangular grid might be squished by such a function, but the intersections are still right angles. Wikipedia has a nice [picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Conformal_map.svg/256px-Conformal_map.svg.png) demonstrating this fact.

The conformal matrices are those in $CO(\mathbb R^n)$ with positive determinant, while those with negative determinant are anticonformal. This is what guarantees that your function $F$ is actually either conformal or anticonformal, not a mix between the two (like conformal at one point and anticonformal at another). If you consider the map $\varphi:\Omega_1\to\mathbb R\backslash\{0\},~x\mapsto\det J_F(x)$, then $\varphi(x)$ is either positive or negative, but never zero. Since $\varphi$ is continuous ($J_F(x)$ is continuous since $F$ is $C^1$ and the determinant is also continuous) and $\Omega_1$ is connected, the image of $\varphi$ is also connected. But then it must be either always positive or always negative, since the negative and positive part of $\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$ are disconnected. So $J_F$ is conformal everywhere or anticonformal everywhere, and thus $F$ is either conformal or anticonformal.

An especially important example of conformal maps are holomorphic functions (with derivative nowhere zero): A function between domains in the complex plane is conformal in $z_0$ iff it is complex differentiable with non-zero derivative in $z_0$. That's essentially what the Cauchy-Riemann equations tell us: they guarantee that the Jacobian is conformal or zero.

Comment: Thanks.. so it is not necessary that $F$ be affine

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook: It's not. Only if $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\mathbb R^n$ and $F$ is surjective. For instance, $\exp:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is not surjective (it's never $0$), and it's conformal on its domain but not affine.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if one can characterise the set of conformal maps $F\colon \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$, where $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I don't know about the general case, but for $n=2$, $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ simply connected and $F$ bijective, they can be characterized with complex analysis. The Riemannian mapping theorem states that simply connected domains not equal to $\mathbb C$ are conformally equivalent (there is a bijective conformal map between them) to the unit disc. The automorphisms (bijective conformal maps from a domain to itself) of the unit disc are known, and the bijective conformal maps between two sets which are conformally equivalent to the disc can be derived from that. But that's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your condition implies

$$c J_F^T = J_F^{-1} \Rightarrow (\sqrt c J_F)^T = (\sqrt c J_F)^{-1}$$

meaning $\sqrt c J_F$ is an orthogonal matrix. Notice that $\sqrt c J_F$ is the Jacobian of the function $G(x) = \sqrt c F(x)$.

[A relevant mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228964/functions-with-orthogonal-jacobian) claims that the only functions $G$ with orthogonal jacobian are affine, i.e. of the form $G(x) = Ax+b$ for some constant orthogonal matrix $A$ and constant vector $b$. So,

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt c} \left( Ax+b \right)$$

Comment: That $F$ is affine is only true if $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=\mathbb R^n$. As a counterexample, the Cayley transformation is such a function from the upper halfplane of $\mathbb R^2$ to the unit disc which is not affine.